# Code First Generate two property same name at runtime

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am using EntityFramework code first. Lets say this is my classes:

```
public abstract class BlockModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ModuleBlockModel : BlockModel
{

}

public abstract class BlockModelParameter
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual BlockModel BlockModel { get; set; }
}

public class ModuleBlockModelParameter : BlockModelParameter
{
   public new virtual ModuleBlockModel BlockModel { get; set; }
}
```

and my DbContext class:

```
public IDbSet<ModuleBlockModel> BlockModels { get; set; }
public IDbSet<ModuleBlockModelParameter> BlockModelParameters { get; set;}
```

when i try to get items, EF creating another property same name. One is null and other is correct.

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBJyN.jpg)

and try to get BlockModel value throws null value.

Is there an EF bug? How can get BlockModel property correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your question? Please remember to clearly state what your desired outcome is, or what you're unclear about if you simply want an explanation of behavior.

Comment: Edited question

Comment: Show your fetch command. Do you have an Include() in your LINQ? `var myBlockModelParmWithBlockModel = context.BlockModelParameters.Include(bmp => bmp.BlockModel).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: @SteveGreene yes. var blockModelParameters = Db.BlockModelParameters.Include(x => x.BlockModel).ToList();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you can't 'hide' the property `virtual BlockModel BlockModel` with the property `new virtual ModuleBlockModel BlockModel` because it is technically a different type signature, even though one is a sub-type of the other.

You can try resolving this with generics (they allow the 'type' to be set dynamically), like this:

```
public abstract class BlockModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ModuleBlockModel : BlockModel
{

}

public abstract class BlockModelParameter<TBlockModel>
    // Guarantee that TBlockModel is sub-type of BlockModel
    where TBlockModel : BlockModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Type of BlockModel will be whatever type is specified for TBlockModel
    public virtual TBlockModel BlockModel { get; set; }
}

// Specify ModuleBlockModel as the generic type argument for BlockModelParameter
// Note: A subtype of a generic class doesn't also have to be generic
public class ModuleBlockModelParameter 
    : BlockModelParameter<ModuleBlockModel>
{
    // Now you can 'hide' the parent's BlockModel property, since the 
    // signatures match - or, better yet, you can omit it entirely, 
    // unless you need a type-specific implementation
    public new virtual ModuleBlockModel BlockModel { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: But now you don't need `public new virtual ModuleBlockModel`

Comment: @GertArnold Quite right, unless he has a type-specific implementation (which he doesn't, in his example)

Comment: @MichaelL. thanks for reply. Gives error at runtime. "BlockModelParameter`1[BlockModel] was not mapped. . Check that the type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation. Verify that the type was defined as a class, is not primitive or generic, and does not inherit from EntityObject.'"